# Visio Shape Data in Shapes and Sub-Shapes

Tags: visio, shapesheet

I'm quite new to Visio and trying to do things with shape data.

Essentially I have a group of elements (geometry, text boxes etc.), and I want the shape data to belong to that group. This bit seems to work.

What I then want to to, is have text fields which are part of that group display the shape data that belongs to the group, but I can't find any obvious way of doing this. Is there something I can put in as a custom formula to reference back to the group's data?

Not sure if I'm using the right terminology, but hopefully makes sense!

Thanks,
A

I tried inserting a field into the sub-shape, but the shape data isn't visible. If I add the data to the sub-shape, it's independent of the main shape.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I tried inserting a field into the sub-shape, but the shape data isn't visible. If I add the data to the sub-shape, it's independent of the main shape.

> [image: Cell references]

1. For make reference to another shape you need define another shape ID, for example 740
2. Press keys **Ctrl**+**F9**, select option **Custom formula** there you must use syntax like `Sheet.740!Prop.Row_1`

Please read more about [cell references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/about-cell-references) or watch [my video](https://youtu.be/PYBDEJSPC0E)…